# AngularJS ng-repeat orderBy orders numbers incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I'm having an issue with using the `ng-repeat` `orderBy` when there are numbers in text.

Sample Data:

```
[
   {booth: 'p1'},
   {booth: 'p2'},
   {booth: 'p3'},
   {booth: 'p4/5'},
   {booth: 'p6/7'},
   {booth: 'p8'},
   {booth: 'p9'},
   {booth: 'p10'},
   {booth: 'p11'},
   {booth: 'p12'},
   {booth: 'p13'}
]
```

When using the `ng-repeat` with the `orderBy: 'booth'` is list it out as such:
p1, p10, p11, p13, p2, ect

I understand this is expected behavior but does anyone know how I can get it to list out the booths in the order that I expect?

Which would be:
p1, p2, p3, p4/5, ect

I have also tried seeing if the issue was because the numbers weren't integers but returned the same issue.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Because I'm too new to SO, I can't resolve my own question yet but here is my answer to the issue. I ended up resolving this by using a custom filter. Note: In the fiddle, there is a parseFloat and a slice, this filter will need modified based on the data you are passing it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3HjP/3/

Answer (score 13):

JavaScript's built-in string comparison won't work for your purposes. I think what is needed is a **natural sort**, to sort the strings the way a human would. I found a solid implementation [here](https://github.com/overset/javascript-natural-sort/blob/master/naturalSort.js) from the blog [here](http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm-with-unicode-support/). It is pretty comprehensive and fairly complex so I won't try to explain the source code here (check the blog for explanation).

You can then create a custom filter for the natural sort and use in your HTML like:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlMain">
        <div ng-repeat="item in data | naturalSort">{{item.booth}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript** - I've left out the implementation of the sort since it's long and not created by me, but check the demo at the bottom to see it in action.

```
app.filter('naturalSort',function(){
    function naturalSort (a, b) {
        // Please see the demo for this code, it is somewhat long.
    }
    return function(arrInput) {
        var arr = arrInput.sort(function(a, b) {
            return naturalSort(a.booth,b.booth);
        });
        return arr;
    }
});
```

The sort implementation in the demo below covers various possibilities (date, hex values, whitespace) that could be used in many situations (though it may be a little overkill for your example).

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/EwSsy/)

Comment: Awesome natural sort algorithm you have here.